# jQuery: How to store data for non-existent elements?

Tags: jquery

What is a good approach of storing data for dom elements that do not exist yet, but when created they obtain that data.

Comment: Can you post some example code please? Your question doesn't seem all that clear.

Comment: This is a very vague question. Please provide information about the DOM elements that are being created. Also, is the data a string, object or array? This information will help us answer your question. If you can add some sample markup and js that would be good too.

Comment: did you try .data...of jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 3):

I'm going make some assumptions here since your question is a little vague at the moment, but it sounds like you want to manipulate DOM elements that do not yet exist, most likely because they will be loaded AJAXily.

jQuery provides a function called `.live()` which lets you bind an event handler to all elements that exist now or in the future.

So, if you wanted to add some data to an attribute of all `<p>` elements--even those that do not yet exist in the DOM--you could do something like this:

```
// hook up an event handler that runs anytime a <p> is inserted into the DOM
$('p').live('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    $(this).attr('title', 'foo');
});

// insert a couple <p> elements and see their title attributes update
$('body').append('<p>hello</p>');
$('body').append('<p>world</p>');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rsobers/TLXEu/3/

**EDIT:** Instead of using attributes to store the data, you can make use of jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function instead.  This is a better place for your custom data.